# Gcompris produce segmentation fault error

Tags: 20.04

The latest version of gcompris has a bug. I used to be able to use it, but since I upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 it stopped working, here is what it does:

```
lea@lea:~$ uname -a
Linux lea 5.4.0-70-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 13:29:52 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
lea@lea:~$ gcompris -v
gcompris-qt 1.1
lea@lea:~$ gcompris
exeCount set to:  2
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
lea@lea:~$ gcompris-qt -v
gcompris-qt 0.97
lea@lea:~$ gcompris-qt 
exeCount set to:  13
qml: enter main.qml (run #13, ratio=1.5384615384615385, fontRatio=1.6174712355185357, dpi=98, userDataPath=/home/lea/.local/share/GCompris)
Downloading resource file "data2/voices-ogg/voices-fr.rcc"
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
lea@lea:~$
```

Could anyone look into it ? I would gladly help and provide as much information as required ?

---

```
$ apt-cache policy gcompris gcompris-qt
 
gcompris: 
Installé : 1:0.97-1build1 
Candidat : 1:0.97-1build1 
Table de version : 
*** 1:0.97-1build1 
500 500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages 
500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages 
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 

gcompris-qt: 
Installé : 0.97-1build1 
Candidat : 0.97-1build1 
Table de version : 
*** 0.97-1build1 500 
500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages 
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ dpkg -S $(which gcompris) 
dpkg-query: aucun chemin ne correspond à /snap/bin/gcompris 
lea@lea:/opt/gcompris/bin$ gcompris 
exeCount set to: 5 Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

carte graphique: 01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS482M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RS482M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200] Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 66, IRQ 17, NUMA node 0 Memory at c8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]

EDIT:
I have 2 versions installed:

- Version 1.1 from snap, command line gcompris
- Version 0.97 from apt-get, command line gcompris-qt

running gcompris --software-renderer DOES WORK

running gcompris --opengl-renderer DOES NOT WORK

running gcompris-qt --software-renderer DOES NOT WORK

running gcompris-qt --opengl-renderer DOES NOT WORK

Conclusions:

- I probably have a driver problem...
- Version 0.97 does not work even in software graphic mode.... please update software depot to 1.1 !

Comment: Works on fresh 20.04 LTS system with Intel graphics. Which video card do you have? What is the output of `apt-cache policy gcompris gcompris-qt` and `dpkg -S $(which gcompris)`?

Comment: UPDATE: I installed gcompris version 1.1, 64 bits, from here: https://gcompris.net/downloads-fr.html and it works fine !

Comment: apt-cache policy gcompris gcompris-qt
gcompris:
  Installé : 1:0.97-1build1
  Candidat : 1:0.97-1build1
 Table de version :
 *** 1:0.97-1build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
gcompris-qt:
  Installé : 0.97-1build1
  Candidat : 0.97-1build1
 Table de version :
 *** 0.97-1build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: dpkg -S $(which gcompris)
dpkg-query: aucun chemin ne correspond à /snap/bin/gcompris
lea@lea:/opt/gcompris/bin$ gcompris
exeCount set to:  5
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)

Comment: carte graphique: 01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS482M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RS482M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200]
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 66, IRQ 17, NUMA node 0
        Memory at c8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]

Comment: Then please post your solution as answer to help other users.

Comment: Thx Norbert for your support, as you could guess I'm not used to this web site nor to ubuntu un general ! I did send my "work around as solution".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And now the fully working solution:

Disable the harware open GL when launching gcompris

> QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1 gcompris --software-renderer

With that command, the app runs fine without any bugs.

Or even better, edit file /etc/environment and add

> LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1

> QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1

Answer (score 1):

In order to help others who may fall on similar situation:

- problem occurs because UBUNTU is no longer supporting proprietary drivers for my OLD ATI card...

Here are some work around that worked for me:

1. Install latests version (1.1) of gcompris via SNAP:

   ```
   sudo snap install gcompris
   ```
2. Test version:

   ```
   gcompris -v # shall display gcompris-qt 1.1
   ```
3. run it with:

   ```
   gcompris --software-renderer
   ```

   => It should work.

Alternate solution:

1. Download version 1.1 from here: https://gcompris.net/downloads-fr.html
   => Direct link: https://gcompris.net/download/qt/linux/gcompris-qt-1.1-Linux64.sh
2. Uncompress is `/opt/gcompris`
3. Run it `/opt/gcompris/bin/gcompris-qt.sh`

   => Alternate command line `/opt/gcompris/bin/gcompris-qt.sh --software-renderer`

UPDATE:
It does not work perfectly, gcompris starts but some of the embedded games fail to start and produce a segmentation fault...